# How to use tolower() with char*?

Tags: c, char, tolower

I have a .txt file with some words and I need them to be lowercase.
How to make each word  lowercase? Just adding tolower() to strtok() doesn't work. What should I add? Or maybe it would be easier to use tolower() on whole file firstly? But how? Please help!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
//#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    char str[5000];
    char *ptr;
    char *words[5000];
    FILE * fp = fopen("hi.txt", "r");
    fgets(str, 49, fp);             
    ptr = strtok(str, ",.; ");         
    int i = 0;
    while(ptr != NULL)  
    {
        words[i]= ptr;
        i++;
        ptr = strtok(NULL, ",.; "); 
    }
    fclose(fp);

    for(int j=0;j<i;j++) {
        printf("%s\n", words[j]);
        //printf("%s\n", tolower(words[j])); // Doesn't work!
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Example:

hi.txt

```
Foo;
Bar.
Baz.
```

Expected output

```
foo
bar
baz
```

Comment: `void main()` --> `int main(void)`.

Comment: `tolower()` is applied to a single letter, not a word. You could try `strlwr()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `tolower` function takes a single character and makes it lower case, so calling it on a `char*` doesn't really make sense. If you know that only the first character of each substring returned by `strtok` is upper case, you need to call `tolower` on that character specifically within your loop. In other words, something like this:

```
while(ptr != NULL)  
{
    ptr[0] = tolower((unsigned char) ptr[0]);
    /* 
    Or equivalently ...
    *ptr = tolower((unsigned char) *ptr)
    */
    words[i]= ptr;
    i++;
    ptr = strtok(NULL, ",.; "); 
}
```

If there are more characters in the string that could be upper case and you want to make sure that they become lower case, you need to iterate through the substring and call `tolower` on every character:

```
while(ptr != NULL)  
{
    for (char *ch = ptr; *ch; ch++)
    {
        *ch = tolower((unsigned char) *ch);
    }
    words[i]= ptr;
    i++;
    ptr = strtok(NULL, ",.; "); 
}
```

Comment: `tolower()` takes an `int` in the range of `unsigned char` or `EOF`.  Robust code uses `*ch = tolower((unsigned char) *ch);` to avoid UB.

Comment: You are correct, I hadn't thought about that. Answer updated.

Answer (score 4):

`tolower()` works only for single characters. You can make use of the below function to convert strings to lower case:

```
printf("%s\n", cnvtolwr(mystring));
```

The implementation of the function is as below.

```
char *cnvtolwr(char *str)
{
    unsigned char *mystr = (unsigned char *)str;

    while (*mystr) {
        *mystr = tolower(*mystr);
        mystr++;
    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: `strlwr` is not standard C.

Comment: @sameerasy it possibly could have been downvoted because: a) `strlwr` is not standard C b) your edit has made it the same concept as my answer, which came first c) people don't like good answers to bad questions. I'm not the downvoter, btw.

Comment: `strlwr` is a bad name for a user function - identifiers beginning with `str` followed by a lowercase letter are reserved in Standard C.

Comment: Now the function is renamed from `strlwr()` (a name which exists in Microsoft's libraries, but is not otherwise standardized AFAIK) to `cnvtolwr()`, is the second sentence "There is a function in `<string.h>` to convert strings to lower case" still accurate?  I think it needs revising.  If you can provide a URL for [`strlwr()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235455.aspx) on MSDN, then you can mention it (but note that MS warns about the name when you use it — it's a mess!).

Comment: @TobySpeight "identifiers beginning with `str` followed by a lowercase letter are reserved in Standard C." --> Unable to find that in the C spec (especially in "7.1.3 Reserved identifiers").  Please provide the C spec citation.  Perhaps it is reserved by some other spec per its rules?

Comment: @chux It's mentioned in N1570 §7.31.13 (part of *Future library directions*).

Comment: @TobySpeight Thanks, I see many other reserved identifiers there (7.31 Future library directions) too.

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked about `tolower`, you could try looping through a string character by character:

```
int i, s = strlen(upperString);
for (i = 0; i < s; i++)
    lowerString[i] = tolower(upperString[i]);
```

If you *don't* need to use `tolower`, you can use `strlwr` to convert an entire string to lowercase (if it's implemented on your system - `strlwr` isn't standard C).

Comment: IMO, it's best not to use `i < strlen(upperString)` in a `for` loop condition; there's no guarantee that the compiler will optimize the call to `strlen()`.  It might do so in this case, but be very careful.  If the compiler can't tell whether the body of the function could change the length of the string, it can't do the optimization, and that converts a linear algorithm into a quadratic one.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes, I agree. I know it'd be better practice to write `int s = strlen(upperString);` and then `for (i = 0; i < s; i++)`, but I was going for simplicity instead of efficiency.